# splitting the root from path in a platform-agnostic way in python

Tags: python, split, path, root

i have a path that describe a folder:

```
s = foo/bar/baz
```

and i need to split the root from everything else. I know that i could use:

```
s.split('/',1)
```

but this is not platform agnostic. Also it seems that the os.path module doesn't implement this feature, so i'm a bit lost. Writing the function from scratch looks like ridiculous amount of work for the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `os.path.sep` variable whose value is defined according to the platform in which the module is installed.

```
import os
s.split(os.path.sep, 1)
```

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for! Thanks ;)

Comment: I would also add os.path.normpath(s).split(os.path.sep, 1) to get the right path every time, in case you cross-platform some path from Linux to Windows.